# How to add IF ELSE condition for rules (for multiple forms) in Jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation to validate multiple forms with same id. Each form contains different fields and I want to add these fields validation rules to jQuery validate function. How can I add these rules for multiple forms (every form has the same id)?

Example

Form1

```
<form id="new-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="email" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Form 2

```
<form id="new-form">
    <input type="text" name="mobile" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="address" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript function

```
$('#new-form').validate({
    // I want to add rules here for both forms
});
```

Comment: One note is, multiple forms in the same dom cannot have same id! use class.

Comment: ID of an element must be unique in a document so you need to rethink about your solution.... and since you have different type of forms define different sets of rules for each form

Comment: Use `class="new-form"` instead of `id="new-form"` and `'.new-form'` instead of `'#new-form'`.

Comment: And please note that SEVERAL of us found it necessary to format and syntax fix your post.

Comment: Why was this tagged with `PHP`?  Please do not tag-spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using jQuery validation to validate multiple forms with same `id`

1. You **cannot** use the same `id` multiple times on the same page.  It's invalid HTML and it will break your JavaScript.  Only the first instance of an `id` will be considered.
2. If you change your `id` into a `class`, then you can freely use it multiple times, and it's valid HTML.

   ```
   <form class="new-form">...</form>
   <form class="new-form">...</form>
   ```

   However, the jQuery Validate plugin will still only consider the *first* instance (a limitation of this particular plugin).  The workaround is to use a jQuery `.each()` together with `class` naming...

   ```
   $('.new-form').each(function() { // select every form on the page with class="new-form"
       $(this).validate() { // initialize plugin on every selected form
           // rules for both forms
       });
   });
   ```

---

> Each form contains different fields and I want to add these fields validation rules to jQuery validate function.

Simply declare all the rules for both forms.  The plugin will ignore any field names that do not exist on the form.

```
$('.new-form').each(function() { // select every form on the page with class="new-form"
    $(this).validate() { // initialize plugin on every selected form
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true
            },
            mobile: {
                required: true
            },
            address: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        // other options, etc.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible reason same id is not working so change id name.then use below code:
$().ready(function() {

// First form validate
        $("#commentForm").validate();

// Second form validate
$("#signupForm").validate({

rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                }
    }messages: {
                firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
}
     });

});